# Angular ng-show not working if parent has ng-if

Tags: angularjs

I have a view where a parent div has ng-if on it, and some child element has ng-show on it.  It seems that the ng-show isn't working correctly when nested under an element with ng-if on it.  Is this an Angular bug or am I doing something wrong?  [See this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CjO8Vhn9KO1hZthNZ2X2?p=preview).

The HTML:

```
<!-- with ng-if on the parent div, the toggle doesn't work -->
    <div ng-if="true">
      <div>
          visibility variable: {{showIt}}
      </div>
      <div ng-show="!showIt">
          <a href="" ng-click="showIt = true">Show It</a>
      </div>
      <div ng-show="showIt">
        This is a dynamically-shown div.
        <a href="" ng-click="hideIt()">Hide it</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br/><br/>

    <!-- with ng-show on the parent div, it works -->
    <div ng-show="true">
      <div>
          visibility variable: {{showIt}}
      </div>
      <div ng-show="!showIt">
          <a href="" ng-click="showIt = true">Show It</a>
      </div>
      <div ng-show="showIt">
        This is a dynamically-shown div.
        <a href="" ng-click="hideIt()">Hide it</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The JavaScript:

```
scope.hideIt = function () {
  scope.showIt = false;
};
```

Thanks,

Andy

Comment: From doc: `Note that when an element is removed using ngIf its scope is destroyed and a new scope is created when the element is restored. ` - it could be a reason of this behaviour

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unlike `ng-show` the `ng-if` directive **creates a new scope**.

So when you write `showIt = true` inside the `ng-if` you are setting the `showIt` property on your child scope and not on your main scope.

To fix it use the `$parent` to access your property on your parent scope:

```
<div ng-if="true">
   <div>
       visibility variable: {{showIt}}
   </div>
   <div ng-show="!showIt">
       <a href="" ng-click="$parent.showIt = true">Show It</a>
   </div>
   <div ng-show="showIt">
     This is a dynamically-shown div.
     <a href="" ng-click="hideIt()">Hide it</a>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Demo [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0m5AURIVbmVIsu1M2bXc?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you!  I was unaware that ng-if created its own scope.

Comment: @Andy like `ng-repeat` as well

Comment: Although your answer technically *works*, it is not a really good solution to the problem. The main issues are that you create an explicit high coupling between 2 scopes and that this doesn't work well with nested scopes (you'll have to keep count and you get things like `$parent.$parent....`). By properly using prototypal inheritance you can eliminate these problems, see also my answer below.

Answer (score 18):

Nemesv mentioned above that you should use `$parent`, but although working, this is *not* the right solution. The problem with this solution is:

1. It creates a high coupling between the scope from `ng-if` and the controller scope.
2. Because of 1, changing `ng-if` to `ng-show` will break your code.
3. As soon as your going to nest more scopes it becomes a mess (`$parent.$parent.$parent....`)

#### Solution:

The quick correct solution is to not define `showIt` directly on your scope, but instead place it in an object (e.g. `component.isVisible`).

#### Explanation:

To understand why this seemingly counter-intuitive solution works and is indeed the correct one you first need to know a little more about how inheritance works with angular:

Scopes inherit from each other using prototypal inheritance, which is the form of inheritance build in into Javascript. This looks as followed:

```
var myScope = {
    showIt : false
}
var ngIfScope = {};
nfIfScope.__proto__ = myScope;
```

When you now *get* a property on the `ngIfScope` object that is not present there it will look in it's prototype to find it there. So if you request `ngIfScope.showIt` the browser does something like this:

```
if (ngIfScope.hasOwnProperty("showIt")) {
    return ngIfScope.getOwnProperty("showIt"); // getOwnProperty does not actually exist in javascript
} else {
    return ngIfScope.__proto__.showIt;
}
```

(in reality this happens recursively, but that's unimportant for this example).

*Setting* a property is much more straightforward though:

```
ngIfScope.setOwnProperty("showIt", newValue);
```

Now we have this information we can see what actually went wrong with your original implementation.

We started with the following scopes:

```
var myScope = {
    showIt : false
}
var ngIfScope = {};
ngIfScope.__proto__ = myScope;
```

When the user clicks the show button the following code is executed:

```
ngIfScope.showIt = true;
```

and the resulting scopes are:

```
var myScope = {
    showIt : false
}
var ngIfScope = {
    showIt : true
}
ngIfScope.__proto__ = myScope;
```

As you can see the new value is written in `ngIfScope`, and not in `myScope` as you probably expected. The result is that `ngIfScope.showIt` overshadows the variable from `myScope` and `myScope.showIt` isn't actually changed at all.

Now lets see what happens if we place the visibility trigger in an object.

We begin with the new scopes:

```
var myScope = {
    component : {
        isVisible : false
    }
};
var nfIfScope = {};
ngIfScope.__proto__ = myScope;
```

Not much changed so far. But now lets see what happens when the user clicks the button:

```
ngIfScope.component.isVisible = true;
```

With some helper variables we can see how this is executed in the browser:

```
var tempObject = ngIfScope.component; 
tempObject.isVisible = true;
```

The first line here is a *get* operation. Since `component` is not defined on `ngIfScope` the Javascript engine will look at the prototype of `ngIfScope` (`myScope`) to find it there, as I explained above. Thus:

```
tempObject === ngIfScope.__proto__.component === myScope.component
```

We are now changing values directly on `myScope.component`, and hence the variables are not overshadowed this time. Resulting scopes are:

```
var myScope = {
    component : {
        isVisible : true
    }
};
var ngIfScope = {};
var ngIfScope.__proto__ = myScope;
```

We now have a working implementation without explicitly binding to a `$parent` scope, and thus there is no (or little) coupling between the scopes. Prototypal inheritance does the work for us, and nested scopes work right out of the box as well.

Comment: This should DEFINITELY be the right answer for this problem

Answer (score 1):

Use function or expression in the both cases, so this variant is working.

```
<div ng-if="true">
  <div>
      visibility variable: {{showIt}}
  </div>
  <div ng-show="!showIt">
      <a href="" ng-click="showIt = true">Show It</a>
  </div>
  <div ng-show="showIt">
    This is a dynamically-shown div.
    <a href="" ng-click="showIt = false">Hide it</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this variant also

```
<div ng-if="true">
  <div>
      visibility variable: {{showIt}}
  </div>
  <div ng-show="!showIt">
      <a href="" ng-click="changeState(true)">Show It</a>
  </div>
  <div ng-show="showIt">
    This is a dynamically-shown div.
    <a href="" ng-click="changeState(false)">Hide it</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

with the code

```
$scope.changeState= function (state) {
  $scope.showIt = state;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

So what Tiddo said about Namesv is true, but also overtly complex.

This'll do it:

```js
scope.pageData = {};
scope.hideIt = function () {
  scope.pageData.showIt = false;
};
```

Containing showIt in an object on the parent scope will ensure it's the same object when using it in children scopes