# Ng-show only updating on interaction

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been chugging along in my project with Angular (pretty new to it), having no major issues, but have bumped into something I can't figure out.

I have a form to allow a user to create an account.  Throughout the form I have error messaging for places where the form could contain errors (eg. Password not long enough, etc.)  In every single area but one, the template updates as I expect it would, not only on this form but on other form in the project.

The offender is this guy:

```
<div id="account-exists" ng-if="createAccountForm.$valid">
    <span class="error" 
        ng-show="error301" 
        translate>
        general.validations.account_exists
    </span>
</div>
```

With the `ng-if` the div is properly inserted into the DOM with the child span intact, however it still contains the `ng-hide` class.  The `error301` is a boolean I'm setting on the scope based on data returned from the server, and using the dev tools can see that it is in fact being updated to `true` where I expect it to.  The thing is, the template does not update automatically to display the error.  It WILL however update if clicked.

I assumed, `$scope.$apply()` could help, but it *freezes the template*. Inspecting the DOM reveals that it DOES help in the sense that it behaves behind the scenes as expected, the JS code in the controller still runs, and the DOM is updated correctly.  Is there anything obvious in my template I'm missing?  Specifically, why would it update with a click?  And has anyone experienced the template freezing on a `$scope.$apply()`?

Comment: you should post more code for sure

Comment: Could be a scope issue - ng-if creates child scope - look into this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884786/angular-ng-show-not-working-if-parent-has-ng-if

Comment: When you update the `error301` variable based on data you got from the server, are you sure you are in a `$digest` cycle?

Comment: @Mike, I checked to see if my update was occurring during a `$digest` cycle, and it turns out its not.  Upon inspection, it looks like the DOM IS updated correctly when using the `$scope.$apply()`, but the view freezes.  Something trickier is happening here.  I can see the console logs I'm setting still running in the background, but the template itself is COMPLETELY frozen.

Comment: @ZivWeissman, thanks for the tip.  I checked into this, but it didn't seem to make a difference.  The DOM is updating correctly in the background, but the template itself is freezing up with a `$scope.$apply()`

Comment: I should note that I've also tried to avoid the `$scope` issues mentioned by @ZivWeissman by changing the `ng-if="createAccountForm.$valid"` to `ng-show="createAccountForm.$valid"` to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely doesn't solve the underlying issues that `$scope.$apply()` is causing with the freezing of the template, but I was at the very least able to get around the issues with this singular error by straight-up manipulating the DOM with 
`document.getElementById("account-exists").classList.remove("ng-hide");` in order to remove the ng-hide that was not being removed without the activation of the digest cycle.

I'd prefer to know why this was happening in the first place, but for now, it's nice to know that as a work-around, this serves my purpose, and that as far as toggling the status of the error I can simply target the element and `remove("ng-hide");` or `add("ng-hide");` when need be.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it works if you use an object. I can't explain why, but in my expirience it helps.

```
ng-show="errors.error301"
```

and then in the controller

```
$scope.errors = {
   error301:false
}
...
...
...
$scope.errors.error301 = true;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this produces the exact same result.  Thanks though.