# Div inside tbody with ng-if not filtering the result

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, html-table

First of all let me please accept angular and html is not my trade.

Following is my scenario

```
<tbody ng-repeat="item in items.ItemList">
    <div ng-if="item.variableName == false">
        <tr>
        <tr/>
        <tr ng-show="isPermitted" ng-animate="isPermitted">
        <tr/>
    </div>
</tbody>
```

I am trying to control the table rows that I wan't to display with `ng-if` inside the div and it is not working. By moving `ng-if` to `tbody` will filter the rows fine but not at `div` level.
Unfortunately, I can't move ng-if to the tbody as I have to deal with the else part of the if condition and in that case there is an array inside each item of the repeater that should render rows separately. 
Following is the output that I want to have once `ng-if` condition works appropriately.

P.S. I am not specific to the `<div>` tag here. I am open to replace div with any other tag as long as it can get me the desired result. 
Here someone might say why not `ng-if` at `<tr>` level? I am using `ng-show` and `ng-animate` so the row with ng-if changes its scope in Doom object and hover over functionality stops working.

```
<tbody ng-repeat="item in items.ItemList">
    <div ng-if="item.variableName == false">
        <tr>
        <tr/>
        <tr ng-show="isPermitted" ng-animate="isPermitted">
        <tr/>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="item.variableName == true">
        <tr>
        <tr/>
        <trng-show="isPermitted" ng-animate="isPermitted">
        <tr/>
    </div>
</tbody>
```

Comment: This approach is  wrong. div is not valid tbody child.

Comment: than what else I can use. Any alternative? tried span also. don't know even if that is valid.

Comment: Use <tr> tag, also use ng-if="item.variableName" and ng-if="!item.variableName".

Comment: @Marko. Can't use ng-if in <tr> tag. my hover over functionality stops working. I have explained that in my post.

Comment: What do you mean by can't use. You must use. No alternative option.

Comment: @Ved. it breaks the hover over functionality. the second row has ng-show and hover over on first row sets the isPermitted value and shows second row for each main row.

Comment: @Ved. here is the reason I am not using it  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884786/angular-ng-show-not-working-if-parent-has-ng-if

Comment: I am not talking about ng-if or ng-show. Your HTML is wrong. `div` should not be `tbody` element.

Comment: @Ved. I understand that. Is there any alternative as ng-if at tr level not sorting my problem.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle link?

Comment: @Ved. I never use fiddle or any such thing before. I need to see that first

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/IgorMinar/ADukg/ this the tool.

Comment: @Ved. Here you go!   http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/11999/

Answer (score 1):

I use this and it's work.
Look exemple in the jsfilddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/12003/

```
<tbody ng-repeat="item in items.ItemList" ng-show="item.variableName">
            <tr>{{item | json}}</tr>

    </tbody>
```

Comment: I know it works well at tbody level and already explained in my question why I am not using this approach.

Comment: Vous pouvez utiliser une nouvelle table à l'intérieur de votre Tbody pour votre condition si vous le souhaitez. Or try to use <script>...</script> and ng-include.

Answer (score 0):

Div won't help you out here as it defies the rules of tbody according to html.

Use ng-container like this instead, it is of no meaning to HTML so it won't defy the rules and you will get your condition fulfilled

```
<tbody ng-repeat="item in items.ItemList">
    <ng-container ng-if="item.variableName == false">
        <tr>
        <tr/>
        <tr ng-show="isPermitted" ng-animate="isPermitted">
        <tr/>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container ng-if="item.variableName == true">
        <tr>
        <tr/>
        <trng-show="isPermitted" ng-animate="isPermitted">
        <tr/>
    </ng-container>
</tbody>
```

Also in your case you can use ng-switch instead of ng-if like this

```
<tbody ng-repeat="item in items.ItemList" ng-switch="item.variableName">
        <ng-container ng-switch-when="false">
            <tr>
            <tr/>
            <tr ng-show="isPermitted" ng-animate="isPermitted">
            <tr/>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container ng-switch-when == "true">
            <tr>
            <tr/>
            <trng-show="isPermitted" ng-animate="isPermitted">
            <tr/>
        </ng-container>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: unfortunately, with ng-container it is still showing all rows with value true and false

Comment: following is the fiddle link where I have tried your approach and it is not working. Can you please advise what is wrong there ?  http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/11999/